# How to generate svg images using python 'quantstat' library

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, svg, jupyter-notebook, report

using quantstat library's report.py module, I am able to successfully generate .html images when I call quanstat.reports.html function, and quanstat.reports.full function to generate .png images for the various graphs, charts, reports.

https://github.com/ranaroussi/quantstats/blob/main/quantstats/reports.py

can someone help me at the earliest how to use the same 'report.py' module or other modules in this 'quantstat' library to generate images in .svg format so that they can be opened in any browser such as google-chrome.

Which files of this library need to be modified or enhanced with python code to successfully generate .svg files ?

following code is generating png images when I am passing file path to 'savefig' in my local. used VS Code as IDE

```
import quantstats as qs

stock1 = qs.utils.download_returns('XLE', period="1y")
stock2 = qs.utils.download_returns('SPY' , period="1y")

qs.reports.full(stock1, stock2)
```

how can I get images in .svg format using same qs.reports.full(stock1, stock2) ?

Comment: This is being answered, click on the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74722834/in-python3-9-13-how-to-know-which-piece-of-code-in-quantstats-library-is-actu

Answer (score 0):

You can make your notebook to output SVG images with:

```py
    # Render charts from quantstats in high resolution
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74721731/how-to-generate-svg-images-using-python-quantstat-library
    matplotlib_inline.backend_inline.set_matplotlib_formats('svg')
```