# In python3.9.13, how to know which piece of code in 'quantstats' library is actually generating reports in .png format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, statistics, png

I am using https://github.com/ranaroussi/quantstats/blob/main/quantstats/reports.py and calling its full() method to generate reports, charts, graphs etc, in .png format.

Any idea which piece of code in reports.py or it's other called module(s) is actually generating, or appending '.png' to image file ?

a quick help on this will be much appreciated. Thank you.

tried analyzing the reports.py & the functions report.py is calling for the full report as
quanstat.reports.full()

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, the code calls [matplotlib's `savefig()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) function, which is the place where `.png` is appended to the filename.

For example, via the following sequence of calls:

- [`full()` -> `plots()`](https://github.com/ranaroussi/quantstats/blob/main/quantstats/reports.py#L317)
- [`plots()` -> `distribution()`](https://github.com/ranaroussi/quantstats/blob/99fb65baeea40aefc4c5eceee8f60689376f32b7/quantstats/reports.py#L733)
- [`distribution()` -> `plot_distribution()`](https://github.com/ranaroussi/quantstats/blob/99fb65baeea40aefc4c5eceee8f60689376f32b7/quantstats/_plotting/wrappers.py#L414)
- [`plot_distribution()` -> `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig()`](https://github.com/ranaroussi/quantstats/blob/99fb65baeea40aefc4c5eceee8f60689376f32b7/quantstats/_plotting/core.py#L720)

The docs for the `savefig()` function explain that if no format is explicitly provided, then `png` is the default and `.png` will be appended to the file name:

> If *format* is not set, then the *format* is inferred from the extension of *fname*, if there is one. If *format* is not set and *fname* has no extension, then the file is saved with `rcParams["savefig.format"]` (default: `'png'`) and the appropriate extension is appended to *fname*.

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick answer @Stuart Berg.

my another ask is, which part of the quanstat code snippet is actually generating the information, that is converted into .png/.svg etc.

my need is, as we can't store files in AWS Lambda, I want to stream the graph related data by converting to json and stream it across to UI or any other consuming API.

A real quick help on this is very much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: Looks like the `returns` data is being prepared via `_prepare_returns()`, called in `full()`.  But why can't you save the `.png` to `/tmp`, and then stream it as a binary blob to the destination of your choosing?